# How do I create multiple groups in a spreadsheet and have them collapsed when the spreadsheet is opened?

Tags: c#, spreadsheetgear

I am attempting to create a spreadsheet with multiple summary rows, all of which are collapsed when the workbook is opened. I've tried using `SummaryRows()`, but it collapses the entire spreadsheet into a single group controlled by a single button. My code below will set all of the groups correctly, but they're all expanded by default.

```cs
// initialize a row indexer
var currentRow = 1;

// iterate through a collection containing several groups
for (var x in arr_x)
{
    // skip a row for the group header
    currentRow += 1;

    // set start row for current group
    var startRow = currentRow;

    // iterate through the current group
    foreach (var y in x.arr_y)
    {
        // do spreadsheet things
        currentRow++;
    }

    // get last row of current group
    var endRow = currentRow - 1;

    // group the rows
    sheet.Cells[$"{startRow}:{endRow}"].Rows.Group();
}

// put expando at the top of the groups
sheet.Outline.SummaryRow = SummaryRow.Above;
```

Ultimately, I'd like to see a structure like below:

```
+ | Group 1
+ | Group 2
+ | Group 3
```

And when expanded:

```
- | Group 1
  | Item 1
  | Item 2
  | Item 3
+ | Group 2
+ | Group 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be trying to group rows that are *immediately adjacent* to each other?  If this is the case, then it would be the expected behavior that each of these groups with the same outline level will get combined / coalesced into one single group.  Microsoft Excel behaves in the same way.  For instance, try using Excel to group Rows 1:5, and then group Rows 6:10.  You will find that you now have a single group consisting of Rows 1:10.

This is just the way that the grouping feature works.  If you need separated groups, you will need to ensure that, for a given outline level, there is at least 1 row of separation between the groups.  For instance, in my above example you could group Rows 1:5, leave Row 6 alone, and group Rows 7:11.

Comment: Yikes, my pseudocode has a bug in it. I'm already doing what you suggest, I'm not attempting to group immediately adjacent rows. I'll fix it to reflect how my code is actually behaving.

Comment: And after reviewing my actual code, I discovered it had the same bug. I was defeated by a missing post-increment.

Answer (score 1):

As per Tim's answer groups require a "header" or a "total" row to be distinct from each other. That can be achieved with a small change to your code:

```
// set start row for current group
var startRow = currentRow + 1;
```

This will create a header row for each iteration of x

You should also set the SummaryRow switch to above so that expand / collapse link is aligned with the header row.

Outline.ShowLevels determines whether the groups are open or closed when the file opens

```
// Collapse all region detail levels.
sheet.Outline.SummaryRow = SummaryRow.Above;

dataSheet.Outline.ShowLevels(1, 0);
```

[image]